# Which one is better creating object of class or call it through interface

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class MyTokenStore: ITokenStore
{
    public IToken CreateRequestToken(IOAuthContext context)
    {
        ...some code here...
    }
    public IToken CreateAccessToken(IOAuthContext context)
    {
        ...some code here...
    }
}
```

Which one of below is better ? 
Option1 - `ITokenStore x = new MyTokenStore()`; OR

Option2 -    MyTokenStore x = new MyTokenStore()

What are the advanatges of both ? 
Can I restrict user from using Option 2 ?

Comment: @MikeBrind I hope you answered the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general good response to this, as it fully depends on you concrete case.

```
ITokenStore x = new MyTokenStore()
```

mades a "slice" over concrete `MyTokenStore` instance where not all members are inside `ITokenStore`, so you missing access to some additional information that may be present in `MyTokenStore` and is not present in `ITokenStore`.

On other hand you create an abstraction layer, so gain a flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Users decide for themselves which version they use. The advantage of option 1 is that the user can really instantiate any class that implements the interface. Say you have a helper class that contains a method

```
DoSomethingVeryUseful(ITokenStore store)
```

then again that method becomes more useful because it can be called with any object that implements said interface.

The advantage of using option 2 is that your class may contain methods that are not part of the interface, and thus those methods can only be used with option 2.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an interface is to expose functionality that is common to all implementer's and is agnostic of the concrete implementation. If you are trying to pass around multiple concrete objects to a consumer that needs to access an interface method, then cast it as an interface.

However, if you need a specific member on the concrete implementation, use that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not which is better question but more what are you going to do with it ? Somethings to consider

1. Are you going to have multiple objects implement the interface ?
2. Are you going to be doing [unit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292197%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) ?
3. Are you going to be doing any in [Dependency Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163739.aspx) ?

   If you can answer yes to at least one of the questions the using a interface is a good idea but if your using a interface just to use a interface you might want to rethink the solution

Comment: Yes, multiple objects will implement interface. We will do unit testing. So I have implemented interfaces

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is the below option. Instead creating "new" object, we can go with contructor injection.

```
public class MyTokenStore{

private readonly ITokenStore;

public MyTokenStore{ITokenStore TokenService)
{
this.TokenStore=TokenService;
}

}
```